# getting Null Pointer Exception when getting of media status in onstatusUpdated() while casting in android

Tags: android, chromecast

I am getting `NullPointerException` when getting of media status in `onstatusUpdated()` method of `RemoteMediaPlayer` while casting first time. How to resolve this and i want to know about the

```
mRemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(mApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>(){});
```

but it works fine when casting the second time with different media while maintaining the session for same chromecast device.

```
mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusUpdated() {
        MediaStatus mediaStatus = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus();
        MediaInfo mediaInfo = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaInfo();

        RemoteisPlaying = mediaStatus.getPlayerState() == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING;                                                 
    }
});
```

Comment: Show what LogCat says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just surround your code with simple null pointer checks as follows:

```
mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {

@Override
public void onStatusUpdated() {
    MediaStatus mediaStatus;
    MediaInfo mediaInfo;
    if(mRemoteMediaPlayer!=null){
        mediaStatus = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus();
        mediaInfo = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaInfo();
        if(mediaStatus!=null){
            //you could even check if mediaStatus.getPlayerState() is not null here
            //before the next line of code
            RemoteisPlaying = mediaStatus.getPlayerState() == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING;         
        }
    }                                                
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @tmalseed, Now working fine without getting exception but am getting RemoteisPlaying values is false even while started media(song)Playing on receiver app, why its happening how can i get the correct value while playing Media on TV?, Plz help me

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question. 'Why is getPlayerState null / not returning MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING even though music is casting to the Chromecast'. If my answer resolved your query, please mark it as 'accepted'.

Comment: As for your second question, are you calling stop()  on the remote media player, before changing songs? If you are, try removing the stop() call and just load the new media. This resolved a similar problem I had.